# Using Mercurial for debugging purposes

Tags: mercurial

I have several files under Mercurial SCM and let's say there is a bug somewhere in my code in this files. I would like to add some message alert windows, automated function calls, etc. to catch this bug. When the bug is caught I would like to correct it and then backout all the stuff I have added for debugging. How can this be done with Mercurial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to commit during the process then you can discard all changes by run

```
hg revert --all
```

You can use `purge` (https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PurgeExtension) command to delete untracked files

```
hg purge
```

If you need to commit during the debug process then the simplest way is to clone a repository and delete this clone when finish.

Comment: I am aware of these options, however, the problem is that I correct the bugs while having debug functions in the code - now, if I revert the changes I also lose my bug corrections but I want to discard only the debug functions...

Comment: Oh, that kind of reverting...  Then you need [record extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RecordExtension).  This extension allows to choose changes for commit interactively.  Similar to interactive staging from git if you familiar with git. TortoiseHG has GUI for this task.

Comment: That will do the job. Thank you. Actually, the [record extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RecordExtension) wiki led me to [darcs](http://darcs.net/) which seems more appropriate for the type of workflow I have imagined.